Is there a way to write generic factories of generic types in any typed language other than C++?
Given the following C++ snippet
#include <print>

template<typename D>
struct data_container {
    D content;
};

template<template<typename> class S, typename T>
class data_transformer {
    S<T> data;

    public:
    data_transformer(S<T> data) : data{data} {}

    auto transform(auto handler) {
        return S{handler(data)};
    };
};

auto convert_to_string = [](auto it){ return std::to_string( it.content ); };

int main() {
    auto data = data_container { 42 };
    // data is a data_container<int>

    auto transformer = data_transformer { data };

    auto result = transformer.transform (convert_to_string);
    // result is a data_container<std::string>

    std::println( "{}", result.content + "!" );
}

Is there a way in any other typed language to correctly describe a thing like the above code? ie a generic type D<G<T>> with a method that returns the same generic type G passed to D but with a different specialization, like G<O>.
NB.
I preferred writing the transform method signature as auto transform(auto handler) to be more concise, but it could have been written with templates. It could be something like this template<class D> S<D> transform(D handler (S<T>)) with convert_to_string written as a normal function instead of a lambda.

fwiw auto transform(auto handler) is a template (just with fancy sweet syntax that makes it look less intimidating)

that's right @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I wrote that in the "NB." part! Still I couldn't find a way to write the same in any other typed language, have you?

You mention C# in the title, but the code is in C++, why? And why the Javascript tag? Tag the language you're actually program in, and don't mention unrelated languages. Please take some time to refresh the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

@Someprogrammerdude Ops! I've fixed the title! Thanks! anyway I was writing js and then I tried to write the same thing in typescript and C# (already knowing how to write it in C++)

I also fixed the question a bit. Any language (other than C++ because I already know how to write it) with some kind of type notation would do!

I think you should narrow the scope of languages that you are concerned with.  For example, if I told you that yes, neolang supports this, would you care?  It feels like there's some other question you are actually trying to ask.  What's your goal?

C++ does not have "generic types", and most languages don't have templates in the manner of C++.

@Wyck of course I would care! my goal originally was to find a way to write that thing in TypeScript (with correct typing) but I couldn't find a way to express that concept in any other object oriented language with static types, so I was curious about what I was missing

What other languages have you looked at?  Simula?  Java?  Ada?  Eiffel? SmallTalk?

@ThomasMatthews I tried C#, Java, Rust and TypeScript (but it all started by adding JsDoc to a script). The best I could make is this concept https://godbolt.org/z/fzbr3hzjW (here is in Java but it is quite easy to write the same in all other languages I tried) but it requires to pass the second function to make the container (the DataContainer::new one), so it is not the same.

Yes, there are lots of languages like this. You are describing Functors (the word has a different use in C++).
data_transformer(x) is approximately Haskell's flip fmap x; i.e. you've partially applied the second argument, the initial value.
Your specific use here is a Comonad, because you are requiring handler to know how to unwrap the S.
If you wanted to provide a typing in Haskell, it would similarly have 3 parameters.
data_transformer :: Comonad s => s t -> (s t -> d) -> s d
data_transformer = flip extend


That's cool, thanks! I hadn't thought about functional languages because I was more focused on object oriented ones, but yes it is the concept of comonad! +1! (if no OOP answare arrives, I'll accept your answer)
